# NHibernate Linq where clause for 3 level tables

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I have three tables, Group -> User -> Account.
Group can have multiple users and user can have multiple accounts.

when i try to fetch all the accounts in the group with query

```
var accounts = accountRepository.FindAll(x => x.User.Group.Id == groupId);
```

where FindAll is method in common repository

```
/// <summary>
/// Find all entities with filter
/// </summary>
/// <param name="expression">Linq expression</param>
/// <returns>IQueryOver of entity of type TEntity</returns>
public IQueryOver<TEntity> FindAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
{
    var query = _session.QueryOver<TEntity>();
    query.Cacheable().CacheMode(CacheMode.Normal);
    return query.Where(expression);
}
```

my query to find all the accounts in Groups does not work as it throw error with message

```
could not resolve property: User.Group.Id
```

Whats the better way to write this query in

Comment: This works good for me --> var accounts = (from user in session.QueryOver<User>()
                               where user.Group.Id == groupId
                               select user.Accounts).List();

Comment: This works because `user.Group.Id` is a value fetched automatically for the `User` entity - it's a foreign key in its table. But to test e.g. `account.User.Group.Id` (like you do in your original question), NHibernate would have to generate a join in the SQL to go from `Account` to `User` and then to `Group`. And the difference is that while `QueryOver` doesn't do this for you, `Query` (Linq to NHibernate) does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Linq to NHibernate instead:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> FindAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
{
    var query = _session.Query<TEntity>();
    return query.Where(expression);
}
```

Unlike `QueryOver`, the Linq provider supports these kind of queries (traversing through the entity hierarchy), turning it into SQL joins.

Comment: @Avi, you are trying to use QueryOver, insetad of Linq